# how to test that my web application can handle "100 users"?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, web

I have a web application built with Java EE 5 (WebSphere 7).  The basic architecture is like so:

```
*.jsp -> ControllerServlet + *Command(s).java -> *Service.java -> *DAO.java -> Oracle DB
```

It works fine, and I'm confident everything is cool, but one of my requirements is to demonstrate the application can support up to 100 simultaneous users.

My automated JUnit tests beat up on the methods of the *Service.java classes, but I have no automated testing for the *.jsp layer.

My question is, what is a good/reasonable way to test/demonstrate that the application can handle the activity of 100 simultaneous users?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Rob

Answer (score 2):

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use a load testing framework such as the [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)